# call a Javascript function when a mobile app page loads

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile app which has multiple pages.  On one of these pages I have some javascript that sends a  request to a php page to get some data.

Now the data is returned perfectly, however it loads as soon as the main index page loads and displays the data immediatley.  What i am trying to do is only show the information when that particular page within the main index.html page is opened.

Below is the code which loads the data immediatley.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://domain/group_list.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
    }

 });
 });
```

I tried to change it to this, but when i do the information doesn't show at all.

```
     $(document).on('pageinit', '#three', function(){
  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://domain/group_list.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
    }

   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code i added was outdated and should be the code shown below, once i made those changes it worked perfectly.

```
  $(document).on("pagecreate","#three",function(event){
         $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
type: "GET",
url: "http://domain/group_list.php",             
dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
success: function(response){                    
    $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
    //alert(response);
}

  });
 });
```